# Scheduling to minimize the truncated gaps

Tags: algorithms, reductions, np-hard

I have a single job of unit length, a set of $n$ slots, and a budget of $B$ units. If the job is scheduled at slot $t$, then it will consume $c(t)$ units of the budget $B$. If the job is not scheduled for a period of $x$ consecutive slots, then a penalty of $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$ occurs. The objective is to schedule the job in order to minimize the sum of penalties.

For example, for $n=12$, if the job is scheduled at slot 1, at slot 3, at slot 6, and at slot $12$, then the sum of penalties is $\lfloor 1/2\rfloor + \lfloor 2/2\rfloor + \lfloor 5/2\rfloor = 0+1+2=3$.

Is this problem NP-hard?

I am trying to reduce the knapsack problem to it. Transforming the values in the knapsack problem to the penalties is somehow difficult, because once the job is scheduled at $t$, the penalty is initialized.

Comment: I guess that the significance of the budget is in the fact that you also want to require $\sum_{t \in T} c(t) \le B$, where $T$ is the set of times at which $T$ is scheduled. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the node cannot spend more than the available budget of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is polynomial-time solvable.
To avoid edge cases it is better to think that the job needs to be scheduled at time $0$ and that $c(0)=0$.

Let $OPT[t,p]$ be the minimum amount of budget that needs to be spent in order to schedule the job in the first $t$ slots with an overall penalty of at most $p$ and with the additional constraint that the job must be scheduled at time $t$.

Let $P(t', t) = \Big\lfloor \frac{t-t'-1}{2} \Big\rfloor$ be the penalty incurred if the job is scheduled at times $t'$ and $t > t'$ and is not scheduled at any time in-between.

Then $OPT[0,p] = 0$ and, for $t>0$:
$$
OPT[t,p] = c(t) + \min_{\substack{t'=0,\dots,t-1 \\ P(t',t) \le p}} OPT\left[t', p - P(t',t) \right] 
$$

The minimum attainable penalty up to time $t$, with the constraint that the job is scheduled at time $t$, is then:
$$
\mu(t) = \min \{p \in \{1,\dots,\lfloor t/2 \rfloor\} \mid  OPT[t,p] \le B \}
$$

And the minimum attainable penalty for your problem is:
$$
\min_{t=0,\dots,n}  \left\{ \mu(t) + P(t,n+1) \right\}.
$$

Notice that there are at most $n \cdot (P(0,n)+1) = O(n^2)$ values $OPT[p,t]$ to compute.

Comment: If the penalty was more general, say $\lfloor x/a\rfloor$. Your algorithm is pseudo-polynomial since $P(0,n)$ depends on $a$. Do you think that the problem is NP-hard?

Comment: Are you thinking of $a < 1$? For $a = \Omega(1)$ the algorithm is still fully polynomial.

Comment: Yes you are right about $a>1$. I have another issue. In your equation, $\min_{t=0,\cdots,n}\{\mu(t)+P(t,n)\}$, how can I find the slots where the job is scheduled? Does this equation mean that the job will be scheduled only once?

Comment: Also, for the reccurrence relation of $OPT[t, p]$, taking the minimum over $t'=0,\cdots,t-1$ would results in $OPT[0,p-P(0,t)]=0$ always, no?

Comment: Regarding the equation $\min_{t=0,\dots,n}\left\{\mu(t)+P(t,n)\right\}$: this equation tells you the **last** time $t$ at which the job is scheduled. Then you can find all the other times by looking at the dynamic programming table. For example, the time that immediately precedes $t$ is the value of $t'$ selected from the minimum of the recursive formula for $OPT[t,p]$ with $p=\mu(t)$. This also tells you the "leftover" penalty $p'= p-P(t',t)$. The second-to-last time at which the job was scheduled is the one selected by the minimum of $OPT[t', p']$, and so on. Repeat until you find all times.

Comment: Regarding the recursion: not necessarily, because the minimum has the additional requirement that $P(t', t) \le p$. Depending on the values of $p$ and $t$ this might or might not be true for $t'=0$.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now. Only one last comment: the minimum value of my problem is the sum of all penalties. Don't you miss a summation in your last minimum ?

Comment: I don't think so. In the last minimum $\mu(t)$ is accounting for all the penalties from time $0$ to time $t$, while $P(t,n)$ is accounting for the last penalty that goes from the last time the job is scheduled (i.e., exactly $t$) to $n$.

Comment: I tried the DP with this instance $B=3$, $n=5$ and $c=[1,2,1,1,2]$. I found $\mu=[0,1,2,2,3,3]$ and $\mu+P=[2,2,3,2,3,3]$. If I did not make a mistake, the minimum is $2$ but the optimal is $0$ since I can schedule the job at slots $1$ and $3$ and $4$.

Comment: If I schedule the job at times $1$, $3$, and $4$, then there is one single idle slot at time $2$, and a single idle slot at time $5$. Thus, we have $\lfloor1/2\rfloor+\lfloor1/2\rfloor=0$. For $x$ consecutive idle slots, I pay $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match with the example in your question where the job is scheduled at time 6 and 12 but you have a $\lfloor (12-6)/2 \rfloor = 3$ term in the final penalty.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. That should be $\lfloor 5/2\rfloor$. I am editing my question.

Comment: The other two terms of my examples are correct: (1) $\lfloor1/2\rfloor$ because there is a single idle slot between $1$ and $3$ and (2) $\lfloor2/2\rfloor$ because there are two idle slots between $3$ and $6$.

Comment: I re-ran the algorithm with the updated penalty function and got $\mu = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]$ and $\mu + P = [2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1]$. Therefore the optimum is $0$.

Comment: Do you think the problem is still polynomial solvable if $B$ was incremental depending on the time slot? Like having $B_t$ each time slot and the available budget at time slot $t$ is $\sum_{s\leq t} B_s$.

Comment: Do you assume in the DP solution that $c(t)\leq B$ for all $t$?